# How to join the first and the last record from table using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, subquery, sql-order-by

I have 2 tables. The first table is - products, the second is revisions.
Joining is making by product.id = revisions.revisionable_id.
I need to get product as 1 record and joined as the first revision (created_at field (2017)) and the last one (created_at (2020)) and get something like this:
Product_name, Revision_2017, Revision_2020
Please help.
Products

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Tesla |
+----+-------+
```

Revisions

```
+----+-----------------+------------+----------+---------+
| id | revisionable_id | created_at | metadata | user_id |
+----+-----------------+------------+----------+---------+
|  1 |               1 | 2017-01-01 | {}       |       5 |
|  2 |               1 | 2018-01-01 | {}       |       5 |
|  3 |               1 | 2019-01-01 | {}       |       5 |
|  4 |               1 | 2020-01-01 | {}       |       5 |
+----+-----------------+------------+----------+---------+
```

Wanted results:

```
+-------------+---------------+---------------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------------+
| Products.id | Products.name | revFirst.created_at | revFirst.metadata | revLast.created_at | revLast.metadata |
+-------------+---------------+---------------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------------+
|           1 | Tesla         | 2017-01-01          | {}                | 2020-01-01         | {}               |
+-------------+---------------+---------------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: added desired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses window functions, available in MySQL 8.0:

```
select p.*,
    max(case when rn_asc  = 1 then created_at end) as first_created_at,
    max(case when rn_asc  = 1 then metadata   end) as first_metadata,
    max(case when rn_desc = 1 then created_at end) as last_created_at,
    max(case when rn_desc = 1 then metadata   end) as last_metadata
from product p
left join (
    select r.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by product_id order by created_at) rn_asc,
        row_number() over(partition by product_id order by created_at desc) rn_desc
    from revisions r
) r on r.product_id = p.id and 1 in (r.rn_asc, r.rn_desc)
group by p.id
```

I could not tell exactly which column in `revisions` relate to the product `id` (`id`? `revisionable_id`?) so I called that column `product_id` instead.

In very recent versions of MySQL (8.0.13), two lateral joins might be a good approach:

```
select p.*, r1.*, r2.*
from product p
left join lateral (
    select created_at as first_created_at, metadata as first_metadata
    from revisions r 
    where r.product_id = p.id
    order by created_at limit 1
) r1 on true
left join lateral (
    select created_at as last_created_at, metadata as last_metadata
    from revisions r 
    where r.product_id = p.id
    order by created_at desc limit 1
) r2 on true
```

---

In earlier versions, I would go for a couple of subquerires:

```
select p.*,
    (
        select r.created_at
        from revisions r 
        where r.product_id = p.id
        order by r.created_at limit 1
    ) as first_created_at,
    (
        select r.metadata 
        from revisions r 
        where r.product_id = p.id
        order by r.created_at limit 1
    ) as first_metadata
    (
        select r.created_at
        from revisions r 
        where r.product_id = p.id
        order by r.created_at desc limit 1
    ) as last_created_at,
    (
        select r.metadata 
        from revisions r 
        where r.product_id = p.id
        order by r.created_at desc limit 1
    ) as last_metadata
from product p
```

For performance, you want the following indexes:

```
revisions(product_id, created_at, metadata);
revisions(product_id, created_at desc, metadata);
```

Comment: Joining is making by product.id = revisions.revisionable_id. Thanks for Your answer, trying

Comment: I am using version 5.7 (( Your approach will not help, anyway thanks

Comment: @АнатолийКостяков: ok, see my update then.

Comment: Didn't know MySQL implemented lateral joins. +1 just for that one.

Comment: @TheImpaler: that's a great improvement in MySQL, in my view!